# Align UIView's subviews

Tags: iphone, uiview, ios4

I have a list of views dynamically populated and then added to a fixed UIView. Now I want a behavior such that all these views get horizontally or vertically stacked up, i.e, all the CGRects get aligned back to back.

I know I can simply go through all subviews and align them based of their previous sibling's frame, but is there a better way to do it?

```
for(UIView *view of [self view].subviews)
{
//code to align
}
```

Moreover, if I delete some view from the queue, the rest of views should realign (gravity effect) to fill up that space. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no container or control that has this functionality. On other platforms there is something like a container where you place controls and it will align those controls horizontally or vertically, and wrapping them on the next line / column, but there is nothing like this on iPhone.
However you can create easily a UIView subclass that creates this functionality ...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the Layer gravity property?